# pip 20.3.4 (python 2.7): Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pipenv, pipenv-install

I'm trying to install library on app built with python 2.7 but getting the same error:
`pipenv install newrelic==5.22.1.152`

```py
Installing newrelic==5.22.1.152...
Adding newrelic to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (3fb6a7) out of date, updating to (527437)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main
    parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main
    requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
    req_dir=requirements_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 385, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 102, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round
    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 301, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 213, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 294, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 474, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmpFSJ8cabuild/lazy-object-proxy/
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 119, in main
    parsed.requirements_dir, parsed.packages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 85, in _main
    requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
    req_dir=requirements_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 385, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 102, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 206, in _resolve_one_round
    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 301, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 234, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 426, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 297, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 260, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/resolve.py", line 213, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 294, in prepare_linked_requirement
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist(finder, self.build_isolation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 127, in prep_for_dist
    self.req.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 474, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 705, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/tmpFSJ8cabuild/lazy-object-proxy/
```

I tried to update libraries:
`pip install --upgrade setuptools` -> `Requirement already up-to-date:(44.1.1)`

`python -m pip install -U pip` -> `Requirement already up-to-date:(20.3.4)`

`pip install ez_setup` -> `Requirement already satisfied:(0.9)`

Does it have something related to the fact, that the app is still using Python 2.7. Or we are still able to install libraries on this version? The last install library was `phonenumbers` 9 months ago and everything was fine since that time.

Comment: I just tried `pip2.7 install newrelic==5.22.1.152` — it was installed just fine. So this version is compatible with Python 2.7, no problem.

Comment: Thx! Can it have something to do with `lazy-object-proxy` in my case? I do not have this lib in `Pipfile` and dependency graph, but it is in the `Pipfile.lock`. I tried to regenerate the `Pipfile.lock` without installing any dependencies but received the same error.

Comment: No idea. `newrelic` by itself didn't bring any dependencies for me.